# No endpoint listening on transfering large file (app config)

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

In the below code i place appconfig when i upload large file it throws no endpoint listening.If the file size is small it works fine.Pls help me to rectify the issue.

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: you should also add these configs in your client as well, did you add them?

Comment: Try to rise the time outs on your configuration, and like @Technovation wrote, the configuration should be the same on the client side as well.